# How to model grassy growth in Blender 2.8x?

Tags: modeling

I want to model grassy growth in Blender like in the picture below where it can be placed on rocks and stuff like that in UE4 so are there any good tutorials on how to model it?
[image]

Comment: You could use a nature asset pack.

Comment: I would like to model it customize to fit my needs.